# How insert and update query with chinese character

Tags: mysql, sql

my database collation is utf8- default collation. I am using mysql database

I want to insert and update query which contains chinese character. How should I do that? Do I need to change my collation in the database?

Comment: You need to add a tag that indicates what DBMS you're using if you want us to help. There are differences between them (Oracle != SQL Server != MySQL != SQLite).

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you made your column type **nchar, nvarchar or ntext.** So you can store Unicode.

Just add an 'N' before your text delimiter in the INSERT/UPDATE statement for fields of the nchar/nvarchar/ntext type:

**INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
            (myfield1, 
             myfield2) 
VALUES      (N'any chinese character', 
             N'any arabic character')
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET    myfield1 = N'any chinese character' 
WHERE  myfield2 = 'something'
```

**Eg:**

```
update Food set FoodName =  N' 杏仁' where ID = 100
```

Comment: Unless this is a blanket answer that works across all DBMS engines, it's wrong. There's no point in posting an answer without knowing what database engine the poster is asking about in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite Hi, He has mentioned tag as sql in question, that's why i put this answer but now he changed as mysql

Answer (score 0):

change your column type to NVARCHAR. so you can store unicode values.

Comment: I could not find NVARCHAR in the data type for my column

Comment: Unless this is a blanket answer that works across all DBMS engines, it's wrong. There's no point in posting an answer without knowing what database engine the poster is asking about in the first place.

Comment: sry, I think the database is mysql

Comment: Do I need to change my collation settting as well?